# Python email png attached pictures to group email,

Tags: python, email, smtp, mime

I followed example at python.org library but get error "'pngfiles' is not defined".
How do I define pngfiles variable? Is this a directory where .png files are? I thought the script should attach all .png files in the directory?
This is my code. SMTP server is working with PS apps I wrote.

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Our family reunion'
me = ('fromMe@gmail.com')
family = ('email1@gmail.com', 'email2@yahoo.com')
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = ', '.join(family)
msg.preamble = 'You will not see this in a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'

for file in pngfiles:
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        img_data = fp.read()
    msg.add_attachment(img_data, maintype='image',
                                 subtype='png')

with smtplib.SMTP('mail.mycompany.local') as s:
    s.send_message(msg)
```